# Pub-Sub mechanism for resending the data to clients

Tags: apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, akka-stream

I have a usecase where I need to deliver the real time events to the clients via websocket. I thought of using Kafka for this. Consuming the msg from kafka and streaming through the websockets. However, when a client get disconnected he need the data from where he left off. So for this seek has to be done with the new consumer and also the common consumer should not deliver the messages until the previous messages for that client has been delivered. So I feel that kafka cannot be best suited for this case. Because there can by many number of clients asking from various offsets.

Also I though of using Akka Actors. Actors created for each client and messages will put into the respective Actor Queue. However, this will not be persistent if server restarts after client disconnected.

Ultimately, we need a queue where each client data will be stored separately and delivered. In case of any issue with the client connection, particular client queue alone wait.

Is there any other pub-sub mechanism / Message Queue which can solve these use cases or any work around can be done in the above mentioned architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

There is Akka Persistence which allows actor state to be stored (event sourcing would probably be a better fit here than the new durable state approach, especially since the latter isn't yet supported in DBs that can handle really high write volumes).

If the clients are all ultimately consuming the same Kafka topic, then it may make sense to effectively duplicate the topic contents in a persistent actor (or more properly, many persistent actors with each responsible for a block of consecutive messages from the topic... an overall persistent actor for the topic might then track when blocks can be purged etc.).  Each client would then have a persistent actor which is tracking where it is in the stream.